# Why does the air flowing above the aerofoil moves faster than the air flowing below the aerofoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation, lift

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqBmdZ-BNig

why can't it be the other way around that the air flowing below the chamber moves faster than the air moving above the upper chamber?

Answer (score -1):

A standard airfoil is curved on top and flat on the bottom.  Air going over the top must move a greater distance than that on the bottom.

Comment: This is the equal-time fallacy, which for some reason is still being taught, by teachers who don't know any better. If this were the explanation, then airplanes could not fly inverted. In fact, they couldn't fly at all.